# Download Javascript resources concurrently, run sequentially?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, seo

*Context: I'm trying to make a fast web page (who isn't?). It accesses resources from multiple domains, the slowest of which is Google Maps.*

I know that normally a web browser blocks while downloading Javascript. Is it possible to just have it download every Javascript file as fast as possible, but retain the execution order? So I might download the Google Maps Javascript, the jQuery library and my code that uses them in parallel, but the browser would hold off running my code until both dependencies are in place.

I've looked at [$script](http://www.dustindiaz.com/scriptjs) and [defer.js](http://www.javascriptoo.com/defer-js) and can't quite work out if they do all of that :) And if they do, how maintainable it is, and does doing that lose me as much performance as it might gain me?

**Edit:** Sorry, I forgot to say that the problem I found with $script was that external script files all had to have $script code inside them to work properly! Which seemed to rule out using it for Google Maps.

Comment: if google maps is the slowest, why don't you download the javascript from google maps and reference it locally?

Comment: Did you look into require.js?

Comment: @RononDex I don't think you're meant to do that? I think the API guarantee only extends to the inclusion of files with correct parameters, and everything will carry on working when they change stuff behind the scenes. Or am I mistaken?